# Google calendar event creation via PHP in the default calendar, not service account calendar

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

To add an event in Google calendar, I created a Google service account from which I got Client Id, Service Account Name and p12 key. Now from my code it is creating an event but it created its own new calendar to insert the event with the name of service account. I want to add event in the default calendar of my Google account. Below is the working code for service account event insert.

```
function calendarize ($title, $desc, $start_datetime, $end_datetime, $gmail_id, $location) 
{
  $start_ev_datetime = new DateTime($start_datetime, new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
  $start_ev_datetime = $start_ev_datetime->format('c');
  $end_ev_datetime = new DateTime($end_datetime, new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
  $end_ev_datetime = $end_ev_datetime->format('c');


  //Google credentials
  $client_id = '**********.apps.googleusercontent.com';
  $service_account_name = '*******.iam.gserviceaccount.com';
  $key_file_location = '**************.p12';
  if (!strlen($service_account_name) || !strlen($key_file_location))
    echo missingServiceAccountDetailsWarning();
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName("App Name");

  if (isset($_SESSION['token']) && $_SESSION['token']) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
      $access_token= json_decode($_SESSION['token']);
      $client->refreshToken($access_token->refresh_token);
      unset($_SESSION['token']);
      $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    }
  }


$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
  $service_account_name,
  array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'),
  $key
);
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  try {
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
  }
}
$_SESSION['service_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
$calendarService = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$calendarList = $calendarService->calendarList;


//Set the Event data
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
$event->setSummary($title);
$event->setDescription($desc);
$event->setLocation($location);
$start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime($start_ev_datetime);
$start->setTimeZone('America/Chicago');
$event->setStart($start);
$end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime($end_ev_datetime);
$end->setTimeZone('America/Chicago');
$event->setEnd($end);
try {
 $createdEvent = $calendarService->events->insert('primary', $event);
} catch (Exception $e) {
 var_dump($e->getMessage());
}

$acl = $calendarService->acl->listAcl('primary');
$userExistFlag = false;

foreach ($acl->getItems() as $rule) {
  if($rule->getId() == 'user:'.$gmail_id){
    $userExistFlag = true;
  }
}

if(!$userExistFlag){
  $scope = new Google_Service_Calendar_AclRuleScope();
  $scope->setType('user');
  $scope->setValue( $gmail_id );

  $rule = new Google_Service_Calendar_AclRule();
  $rule->setRole( 'owner' );
  $rule->setScope( $scope );

  $result = $calendarService->acl->insert('primary', $rule);
}

echo 'Event Successfully Added with ID: '.$createdEvent->getId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember a service account is not you.  A service account is its own dummy user.  It has its own google calendar account this is why its creating events on Its calendar and not yours.

Take the service account email address and share your personal calendar with the service account like you would share it with any other user in the web application.  Once you have shared the calendar with the service account it will have access to it.  Note the calendar Id and you will be able to use that to update your calendar.

**Background Info**

```
$createdEvent = $calendarService->events->insert('primary', $event);
```

primary donates the primary calendarof the currently authenticated user.  That being the service accounts primary calendar.